# How to make grub configuration persistent

Tags: kali-linux, nouveau

I recently did some tweaking on my Kali Linux where I tried installing `nvidia` graphics driver and I had to disable `nouveau` driver.

- I tried reverting my changes by deleting `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf` and other `nvidia` configs that disables `nouveau` but that didn't work.
- I booted to grub where `nouveau.modeset=0`.
- I removed the line then started it up ran `update-grub` restarted hoping it would be persistent but it's not.

I have no idea why the changes I make is not persistent how do I fix this?

Comment: For tweaking, I strongly suggest to do system backups. For example, `Timeshift` app is extremely useful. Right now - you have too many variations of what could gone wrong. for starters, the GRUB should not be responsible for problems with video.

Answer (score 1):

The framebuffer display drivers (module `nouveau`) or the kernel part of the `nvidia` driver (modules `nvidia`, `nvidia_modeset`, `nvidia_drm` and/or `nvidia_uvm`) are normally loaded very early in the boot process, when the system is still running from initramfs. Once the real root filesystem is mounted and the real `/etc` becomes visible to the kernel, the attempts to load (the kernel part of) the framebuffer driver(s) are already done and won't be automatically re-attempted.

Because of this, it is important to update your initramfs file after making any configuration changes that affect early boot. Since Kali is based on Debian, the command `update-initramfs -u` should handle it pretty much automatically.

The `update-initramfs -u` command will copy any relevant configuration files (including the contents of the `/etc/modprobe.d/` directory *as they exist at the time of running the command*) and will package the copies into an initramfs file.

- If you ran `update-initramfs -u` as part of the installation of the `nvidia` driver (or the driver installation ran it for you), then reverting the changes by deleting `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf` was not sufficient: the initramfs will still contain the blacklisting, and it will still take effect when the display driver is loaded. Run `update-initramfs -u` as root to fix this by updating the initramfs file to match the current contents of `/etc`.
- Any changes to kernel boot options *done within GRUB* will not be persistent: GRUB's filesystem drivers are all very simple and read-only. `update-grub` will recreate the actual GRUB configuration file (in Debian and related distributions, essentially always `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`) based on the contents of the `/etc/default/grub` file and the scripts in `/etc/grub.d/` directory. To remove `nouveau.modeset=0` from the kernel boot options persistently, you must edit `/etc/default/grub`, then run `update-grub` to recreate the `grub.cfg` file.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm it now it is fixed